# Filtering outgoing TCP traffic to specific IP with macOS Network Extension

Tags: macos, networkextension, macos-system-extension

I'm using Network Extension to filter the outgoing TCP traffic to specific IP:

```
import NetworkExtension
import os.log


class FilterDataProvider: NEFilterDataProvider {

    override func startFilter(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        let endpoint = NWHostEndpoint(hostname: "111.111.111.111", port: "0")
        let networkRule = NENetworkRule(remoteNetwork: endpoint,
                                               remotePrefix: 0,
                                               localNetwork: nil,
                                               localPrefix: 0,
                                               protocol: .TCP,
                                               direction: .outbound)
        let filterRule = NEFilterRule(networkRule: networkRule, action: .filterData)

        // Allow all flows that do not match the filter rules.
        let filterSettings = NEFilterSettings(rules: [filterRule], defaultAction: .allow)

        apply(filterSettings) { error in
            if let applyError = error {
                os_log("Failed to apply filter settings: %@", applyError.localizedDescription)
            }
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    }
    
    override func stopFilter(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func handleNewFlow(_ flow: NEFilterFlow) -> NEFilterNewFlowVerdict {

        guard let socketFlow = flow as? NEFilterSocketFlow,
            let remoteEndpoint = socketFlow.remoteEndpoint as? NWHostEndpoint,
            let localEndpoint = socketFlow.localEndpoint as? NWHostEndpoint else {
                return .allow()
        }

        os_log("Got a new flow with local endpoint %{public}@, remote endpoint %{public}@, direction %{public}@", localEndpoint, remoteEndpoint, flow.direction == .inbound ? "inbound" : "outbound")

        return .allow()
    }
}
```

However, I receive callbacks also for the IPs that I'm not interested in:

```
2021-06-02 06:58:53.333438-0700 0x1bf8     Default     0x0                  666    0    com.mycompany.MyApp: Got a new flow with local endpoint 0.0.0.0:0, remote endpoint 111.111.111.111:80, direction outbound
2021-06-02 06:59:27.487968-0700 0x1d11     Default     0x0                  666    0    com.mycompany.MyApp: Got a new flow with local endpoint 0.0.0.0:0, remote endpoint 111.222.111.222:80, direction outbound
2021-06-02 07:00:06.118907-0700 0x1d74     Default     0x0                  666    0    com.mycompany.MyApp: Got a new flow with local endpoint 0.0.0.0:0, remote endpoint 123.123.123.123:80, direction outbound
```

Also, when I try to intercept not only TCP traffic but also UDP, providing ".all" instead of ".TCP" in NENetworkRule constructor, I start receiving outbound AND INBOUND traffic from and to many different IPs.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At less one problem I've solved. The "remotePrefix" has the meaning of subnet mask. Providing it's value of 0 was the mistake. To catch only the IP I am interested in, need to set it to 32. Described [here](https://medium.com/netdevops/what-are-network-prefixes-e1923a1d6a3e).

Answer (score 0):

Define the rule that you wish to allow. than, choose `defaultAction = NEFilterACtionFilterData` for all traffic that doesn't match this rule.

```
NSMutableArray<NEFilterRule *>* rs = [NSMutableArray arayWithCapacity:1];

NEFilterRule*r=[[NEFilterRule alloc] initWithNetworkRule:[[NENetworkRule alloc] 
initiWithDestinationNetwork:[NWHostEndpoint endpointWithHostname:@"111.111.111.111" port:@"0"] 
                     prefix:0 
                   protocol:NENetworkRuleProtocolTCP 
                                                 action:NEFilterActionAllow];

[rs addObject:r];

NEFIlterSettings* s = [[NEFilterSettings alloc] initWithRules:rs defaultAction:NEFilterACtionFilterData];

// 'self' is the packet filter provider implementation of yours
[self applySettings:s completionHandler^(NSError * e) { ... }
```